# How do I parse this matrix?

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

Just for fun, I decided I wanted to write a Python program that does mathematical operations on Matrices (rectangular collections of number data) without using the NumPy library, which was butilt specifically for matrix math (Linear Algebra). I have completed that program in Python, but since then, I decided I want to try to turn that into Java code. Since Python is not strictly-typed like Java, my issue currently is parsing the user's stringed matrix input in the form `x x x, x x x, x x x, ...`, where each number is separated by a space, and each row is separated by a comma and a space. I have to parse that into `[[x, x, x], [x, x, x], [x, x, x], [...]]`

I have created a separate function that will return the `double[][] matrix` and will receive user input, but for testing I have left its return type void and given it a default matrix of `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` in the form `"1 2 3, 4 5 6, 7 8 9"`.

```java
// Takes text input; transforms it into array of arrays (matrix)
// parse 'x x x, x x x, ...' into [[x, x, x], [x, x, x], [...]]
private static void parseMatrix(String matrix) {
    // Separates each row (one array results)
    String[] partMat = matrix.strip().split(", ");
    // Supposed to create arrays out of rows (multiple arrays result)
    for (int i = 0; i < partMat.length; i++) {
        partMat[i].split(" ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(partMat));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    parseMatrix("1 2 3, 4 5 6, 7 8 9");
}
```

In this testing code, I want it to print `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` 3 times, but it prints `[1 2 3, 4 5 6, 7 8 9]` 3 times. What am I missing?

Comment: Looks to me like you are printing `partMat`, not the result of `partMat[i].split()`

Comment: Wouldn't I need 2 for loops? One for the rows, and one for each item within the rows?

Comment: How do I make the Stream answer by NIkolai Dmitriev readable? I believe it works, but the resulting array is hard for me to parse because of the Double class being used in place of primitave data type double

Comment: you mean, hard to access. I don't think so, you can assign a `Double D = 0d;` to a `double d = D` without explicit conversion (`double D = Double.valueOf(d)`), its done implicitly and referred to as "unboxing". But this stream stuff is an own type of thinking, I wouldn't feel comfortable to incorporate it in my code without knowing how and why it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is 2D array, so the parsing should be done as such.

```java
private static double[][] parseMatrix(String matrix) {
    String[] parentMat = matrix.split(", ");
    double[][] childMat = new double[parentMat.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < parentMat.length; i++) {
        String[] child = parentMat[i].split(" ");
        childMat[i] = new double[child.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < child.length; j++) {
            childMat[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(child[j]);
        }
    }
    System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(childMat));
    //[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]]

    return childMat;
}
```

Comment: I have to convert the acutal `String[][]` data type to a `double[][]` data type, not just make a `String[][]` look like a `double[][]`

Comment: @Hy-tech I have updated the answer, though it seems a bit verbose. I personally recommend the shortest and cleanest code with a `Stream`

Comment: I do not fully understand Streams, so I am going with this one, and this one worked. I'm guessing the `childMat[i] = new double[child.length];` statement was to circumvent the issue of childMat having been declared outside the for loops and not having a length for each inner array, right?

Answer (score 2):

The `aString.split(" ")` call returns an array of results, which you are ignoring, but *does not modify the original array*. You need to use its result to store the newly-parsed row somewhere:

```
private static double[][] parseMatrix(String matrix) {
    String[] partMat = matrix.strip().split(", ");
    double[][] rows = new double[partMat.length][];
    for(int i = 0; i < partMat.length; i++) { 
        String[] row = partMat[i].split(" ");  // <-- store result
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
        // will fail unless you use Double.valueOf to parse each element
        // rows[i] = row;
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: Since I am dealing with a 2D array, wouldn't I require 2 `for` loops? The second would probably be after the print statement if so.

Comment: finishing the code indeed requires a second loop right where the `// will fail` comment is located, converting each of the strings in `String[] row` into doubles using `Double.valueOf(s)` on each

Answer (score 0):

If you're content with Double[][] a one liner is possible

```
private static Double[][] parseMatrix(String matrix) {
    return Stream.of(matrix.split(", "))
            .map(row -> Stream.of(row.split(" ")).map(Double::valueOf).toArray(Double[]::new))
            .toArray(Double[][]::new);
}
```

It is basically a csv format, so commons-csv also does the parsing job, with a few ugly tweaks:

```
List<CSVRecord> rows = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(' ')
            .parse(new StringReader(matrix.replace(", ", "\n")))
            .getRecords();
```

Some think, that all this object-, split- and stream- and library stuff is really lame and its much more cool to create this functionality entirely in 1st person mode, really low-level old school, scanner, parser, what not, in the venerable, centuries old ascetic tradition of using `char[]` only. Its [Possible](https://github.com/curiosag/redundant_csv_parser), and this way its also possible to increase the [LoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code) by a factor 70 without introducing unnecessary code, well... not much, unit tests not counted.